# Unable to make the facebook “like” button to work on this site, any ideas?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This is the site >> ( removed ) ***the site has been redone since this question has been post, so it was useless.***

I'm using a plugin and also trying to use the usual facebook like button that it's explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Anyhow, the like button simply doesn't work or appears to have a # url.

I looked in StackExchange for any similar question, but all the problems seems to be different, any idea or link to an answer will be highly appreciated.

EXAMPLE CODE:

There's no much code to show really, just the one that facebook gives you on their site, like this:

This goes right after the  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this in the position I want the button to appear:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.elsolitario.com/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

it should be that simple, but it seems that won't work no matter what.

Comment: can we see some of your code?

Comment: There's no much code to show really, just the one that facebook gives you on their site, like that one up here

Comment: Solved, it seems that other plugin added a css property for all the iframes ( z-index: -1 ), so even if the button was shown the iframe was blocked for clicking. I solved the thing adding another rule just for the facebook button setting the z-index to 1000

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you forgot to add appId parameter in

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1
```

it should be

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID
```

Here's some code i'm using...
Header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Right after header:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
</script>
```

And the button wherever you need it:

```
<fb:like href="YOUR_LINK" show_faces='false' layout="button_count" stream='false' header='false'></fb:like>
```

Comment: Do I have to create an app then?, isn't possible to create a regular like button without adding the app code?.

I'm saying this because that's exactly the code that facebook gave me, without the APP_ID

Comment: As far as i remember, you have to create app, that will be associated with your web page. The reason you got code without APP_ID is probably because you don't have any existing apps yet (for me, code generator selected first app in list and inserted it's id)

Comment: Still not working.

I created the app id and set the domain in the faecbook app to the web, also I checked in the lint tool of facebook the url and says everything it's ok but the "like" buttons still don't work.

Comment: Doesn't even work on the single posts >>>>  http://www.elsolitariomc.com/2012/05/willis-earl-beal/

Comment: I see that you have <a></a> tag around your like button, you should remove it. the code the div generated by facebook is enough for page to be liked. You can place it in another div if you want to apply some styles to it

Comment: I didn't add any anchor tag around that, must be the facebook script, this is all the code I got in the place where I put the facebook like button, just the code that the facebook like page gave me >>>> 

<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>

Comment: if you mean the "like" button from the top, ignore it, it's the addthis plugin, the bottom "like" button it's the one that's been add as facebook requires, and still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, perhaps said plugin is messing up the like button? Becasue i can see 2, one of them (plugin one) is clickable, the other one isn't.

Comment: I'll disable the plugin, just in case, but even like that it won't work, check it out, now it's just the "oficial" facebook like button with the facebook code.

Comment: I've went through some of my code and found out that i'm using different code for the like button. I'll edit my answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: I removed the scripts and code I had and used yours, but I'm afraid still doesn't work. It really strange, because doesn't even change the cursor to the clicking hand.